# how to create a separate array of json object having common id

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, arraylist

hello every one i have situation and needs your help , i have json array having common id firstly i need to take common id from all json obj and then place each common json to separate array

```
var myArray = [ {"id" : 1, "text": "Number one", "time": "16 03 13"},{"id" : 1, "text": "Number two", "time": "14 03 13"},{"id" : 1, "text": "Number three", "time": "13 03 13"},{"id" : 2, "text": "Number one", "time": "13 03 13"}] 


I want output of this object as 

 var myArray = {    
[           
"1" : [
  {"text": "Number one", "time": "16 03 13"}, 
  {"text": "Number two", "time": "14 03 13"},  
  {"text": "Number three", "time": "13 03 13"} 
]
]
[
"2" : [
  {"text": "Number one", "time": "13 03 13"}   
]
```

]}

```
I want to place common ID in a each separate JSON array to make 2d array
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var myArray = [ {"id" : 1, "text": "Number one", "time": "16 03 13"},{"id" : 1, "text": "Number two", "time": "14 03 13"},{"id" : 1, "text": "Number three", "time": "13 03 13"},{"id" : 2, "text": "Number one", "time": "13 03 13"}] 



const uniqueIds  = myArray.map(elem=>elem.id).filter((value, index, self)=>self.indexOf(value) === index)


const contentsOfId = (id)=>{
    return myArray.filter(elem=>elem.id === id).map(({text,time})=>({text,time}))

}

const results = uniqueIds.map(id =>{

    const obj={}
    obj[id]=contentsOfId(id);
    return obj;

})
```

The Output will be

```
[{"1":[{"text":"Number one","time":"16 03 13"},{"text":"Number two","time":"14 03 13"},{"text":"Number three","time":"13 03 13"}]},{"2":[{"text":"Number one","time":"13 03 13"}]}]
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of having multiple loops you can achieve this linearly.

```
var myArray = [{ "id": 1, "text": "Number one", "time": "16 03 13" }, { "id": 1, "text": "Number two", "time": "14 03 13" }, { "id": 1, "text": "Number three", "time": "13 03 13" }, { "id": 2, "text": "Number one", "time": "13 03 13" }]
const outputArray = {}
myArray.forEach((ele)=>{
    if(outputArray[ele.id]){
       outputArray[ele.id] = [...outputArray[ele.id], {...ele}]
    } else {
       outputArray[ele.id] = [ele]
    }
});
console.log(outputArray)
```

The Output will be

```
{ '1':[ { id: 1, text: 'Number one', time: '16 03 13' },
        { id: 1, text: 'Number two', time: '14 03 13' },
        { id: 1, text: 'Number three', time: '13 03 13' }
       ],
  '2': [ { id: 2, text: 'Number one', time: '13 03 13' } ]
 }
```